# How can I iterate through a list only a specific amount of times? i.E to cout the top 5 elements

Tags: c++, list, for-loop

I have a list

```
list<pair<Zeitpunkt, double>> l_tempdiff;
```

And I only want to  `cout` the first 5 elements.

I only know the way of couting the whole list with:

```
for (auto elem : l_tempdiff)
{
    cout << elem.first << elem.second << endl;
}
```

I dont know how to acces my elements when I use:

```
for (it = l_tempdiff.begin(); it != l_tempdiff.end(); ++it)
{

}
```

And I guess I need to change the `l_tempdiff.end()` to some other value but it doesn`t seem to take just the number`5`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `std::list` iterators are not random access you cannot just increment them like `l_tempdiff.begin() + 5`.  What you can do is use [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) to increment the iterator the required number of times.  That would looks like

```
for (auto it = l_tempdiff.begin(), end = std::next(l_tempdiff.begin(), 5); it != end; ++it)
{
    // use `*it` here
}
```

Before doing this though you should make sure the list is big enough because if it isn't then you'll have undefined behavior.

Comment: This kind of throws me an error: Wetterdienst.cpp:128:80: error: redefinition of 'it'
    for (auto it = l_tempdiff.begin(), end = std::next(l_tempdiff.begin(), 5), it(HERE) != end; ++it)

And still leaves me with the question on how to access my pair values as I did easily with the for (auto elem : l_tempdiff) and elem.first

Comment: @CraigHarrison do you want to just print the values or print and do some additional stuff in the loop?

Comment: @CraigHarrison Fixed.  I had a `,` where there should have been a `;`

Comment: I only want to print the values

Comment: @NathanOliver Okay I figured out it works with cout << it->first << it->second<<endl;

Answer (score 1):

You only want to output the first five elements?
Well, a for-range-loop is a good place to start, just add the additional constraint as a break-condition:

```
int i = 0;
for (auto&& elem : l_tempdiff)
{
    if (5 < ++i) break;
    cout << elem.first << elem.second << endl;
}
```

I change `auto` to `auto&&` to avoid needless copying.

As an aside, consider reading "*[Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)*" and "*[C++: "std::endl" vs "\n"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)*".

Answer (score 0):

```
 list<pair<Zeitpunkt,double> > :: iterator it;
 int m = 0;
 it = l_tempdiff.begin();

 while( it != l_tempdiff.end() && m < 5)
 {
  cout<<it->second<<"\n"; 
  m++;
  it++;
 }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 auto it = l_tempdiff.begin();
 auto end = l_tempdiff.end();

 for (int count = 0; count < 5 && it != end; ++count)
 {
     std::cout << it->first << it->second << std::endl;
     std::advance(it);
 }
```

This prints the first five pairs (or all the pairs, if there are less than 5).

`count` is used to control the maximum number of elements to be printed.

`it` is an iterator that, in each iteration of the loop, references the current pair.

Note that advancing an end iterator gives undefined behaviour.  So it is necessary to terminate the loop if the end iterator is reached  (hence the `it != end` test in the loop condition) or if the maximum number of elements (`5`) is reached.